# Removing home and all Categories from breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs

I am trying to remove the breadcrumb link home.

Also all categories just so it isnt to much writing as a lot of our categories names are rather long.

For example

So instead of it saying

> HOME->ALL CATEGORIES->TOPS->POLO-TOPS

I want it to say

> TOP->POLO-TOPS

I have tried to just add this if statement to the breadcrumbs.phtml

```
<?php if ($_crumbName != 'home' ){?>
```

Which seems correct but it isnt doing anything so i dont know if i have this in the wrong place or am just going about this wrong. I have entered my full code below.

```
  $crumbsLevels = $this->getAllBreadcrumbs();
?>
<?php if($crumbsLevels && is_array($crumbsLevels)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <?php foreach ($crumbsLevels as $crumbs): ?>
    <?php if ($crumbName != home ){?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumb): ?>
        <li <?php if ((!empty($_crumb['category_id']) || count($crumbs) >4) && !$_crumb['last']) { ?>typeof="v:Breadcrumb"<?php } ?><?php if (!empty($_crumb['hidden'])) { echo 'style="visibility: hidden;"'; } ?>>
        <?php if(!empty($_crumb['link'])): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_crumb['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?>" <?php if (!empty($_crumb['category_id'])) { ?>rel="v:url" property="v:title"<?php } ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?></a>
        <?php elseif($_crumb['last']): ?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?></strong>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_crumb['title']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!$_crumb['last']): ?>
            <span>  </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php }?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know i didnt mention the all categories but wanted to egt the Home link done first and i assume it will just be the same but using the category ID or the name 'All Categories'?

If someone could let me know where i am going wrong or what is should be writing in that would be great thank you.

Comment: Your code worked for me, even without quoting `home` in the if statement, so if it wasn't working for you you probably need to check your caches, and that you're actually using the template file that you're including.

Comment: @Richard you are completely right I was looking in the wrong folder. and the folder in the file i am using looks nothign liek the one above so i will edit my question. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to remove breadcrumbs from home page and category pages, then you can do it easily by a layout update. Use `local.xml` file to do this.

File : `app\design\frontend\<your_package>\<your_theme>\layout\local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
           <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
           <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="root">
           <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
 </layout>
```

### EDIT

This job is somewhat difficult to achieve. This is because, by default magento adds `home` breadcrumb and `category` breadcrumbs from two different files. So basically you cannot avoid a rewrite atleast. So make your work more clean, you need to create a module. I am going to call this module `Rkt_Breadcrumbs`. First create `config.xml` for your module.

`app\code\local\Rkt/Breadcrumbs/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_Breadcrumbs>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Rkt_Breadcrumbs>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <breadcrumbs>Rkt_Breadcrumbs_Block_Breadcrumbs</breadcrumbs>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

So our module just tells to magento that, it needs to rewrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs` with our class `Rkt_Breadcrumbs_Block_Breadcrumbs`. Now we can define our rewrite class

File : `app\code\local\Rkt/Breadcrumbs/Block/Breadcrumbs.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_Breadcrumbs_Block_Breadcrumbs extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if ($breadcrumbsBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {

            $title = array();
            $path  = Mage::helper('catalog')->getBreadcrumbPath();
            array_shift($path);
            foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
                $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
            }

            if ($headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
                $headBlock->setTitle(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
            }
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Here we are rewriting the method `_prepareLayout()`. Here if you compare the two methods, you can see that our new `_prepareLayout()` method do two jobs.

1. It removes `Home` breadcrumb
2. It removes root category from the category array which is generated via the helper class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data::getBreadcrumbPath()` using the method `array_shift`. That's it. You are done. Dont forget to add the activation file of the module. It looks like this.

File : `app\etc\modules/Rkt_Breadcrumbs.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_Breadcrumbs>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends> 
                <Mage_Catalog/>
            </depends>
        </Rkt_Breadcrumbs>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Note :** This will resolve issues in category page only.

Comment: i think you misunderstood, i dont want to remove them from them actual pages i want to remove them as links when you are on any page. So instead of it saying HOME->ALL CATEGORIES->TOPS->POLO-TOPS. I want it to say TOP->POLO-TOPS. I will make that clear in my question

Comment: is  POLO-TOPS product or category?

Comment: you need this feature only for categories ? what about homepage ? what about other pages ?

Comment: POLO-TOPS is a category but even on product pages i dont want 'HOME' or 'ALL CATEGORIES' i just dont want Them to show on any pages

Comment: `ALL CATEGORIES` is your root category ?

Comment: yea it is the root category

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: You're using array_shift wrong in the code there. I think you mean 
`$path  = Mage::helper('catalog')->getBreadcrumbPath();
array_shift($path);` Or you're setting path to the first element of the list, not chopping it off.

Comment: @Richard : I think there is no problem in that code. Because `Mage::helper('catalog')->getBreadcrumbPath()` gives an array actually and I want to remove the first element from that array.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. You're assigning the return value of array_shift to $path. array_shift isn't returning the array minus it's first element, it's returning the first element. See https://gist.github.com/rbrown/9baec5e76562982d3de9

Comment: @Richard : oh gotcha... you are absolutely right. :) thanks for the tip

Comment: @Richard : I updated my answer as you have pointed out. More power to you

Comment: it seemed mean to point out a typo in all that code

Answer (score 2):

**Remove specific crumb from breadcrumbs**

**1. Extend class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs and create method removeCrumb()**

> app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <namespacemodule>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
            </namespacemodule>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                     <html_breadcrumbs>Namespace_Module_Block_Page_Html_Breadcrumbs</html_breadcrumbs>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Page/Html/Breadcrumbs.php

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Page_Html_Breadcrumbs extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs {

    function removeCrumb($crumbName) {
        if ((!isset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName])) || (!$this->_crumbs[$crumbName]['readonly'])) {
            unset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName]);
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

**2. Call this method from Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/view.php  to local/Catalog/Block/Product/view.php after line**

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘catalog/breadcrumbs’);
```

The string which you should pass through method removeCrumb is nothing more than ‘category’+category_id.

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs'); 
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->removeCrumb('home');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->removeCrumb('allcategory'); // You
```

[<strike>More info</strike>](http://www.magento3.com/magento-articles/remove-specific-crumb-from-breadcrumbs/)

You can also remove breadcrumbs via your local.xml (preferred method) as you're able to use specific handles. The below example attaches to default which is on every page, but you can be more specific than this.

```
<default>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="removeCrumb"><crumbName>home</crumbName></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: What is ` || (!$this->_crumbs[$crumbName]['readonly'])` for?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is managed it *Category and product page breadcrumbs* using `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data` class function `getBreadcrumbPath` function here magento check *Category  and product object is exits in current category depends on this magento create breadcrumbs*.

**Note:**

You need to write this class.

First depend on *current category  Path* create  an `array` which containing  a *hierarchical category tree ids* then

```
$pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
$pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));
```

then  create breadcrumbs using below code

```
$categories = $category->getParentCategories();

// add category path breadcrumb
foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
    if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && $categories[$categoryId]->getName()) {
        $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
            'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
            'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getUrl() : ''
        );
    }
}
```

**HOME->ALL CATEGORIES->TOPS->POLO-TOPS**.

```
As you want to
```

**TOPS->POLO-TOPS**. that means you want only last category then

you  need modify code if it category page

```
$pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
$pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));

$categories = $category->getParentCategories();

// add category path breadcrumb
// put All Category id in loop to remove All category from crumns
foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
    $categoryId= end($pathIds);
    if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && $categories[$categoryId]->getName()) {
        $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
            'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
            'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getUrl() : ''
        );
    }
}
```

And for `remove Home link from catalog` page you need rewrite class

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs` and  and remove

```
$breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb('home', array(
    'label'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Home'),
    'title'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Go to Home Page'),
    'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()
));
```

from rewrite code

Comment: you are in the right path. But editing core code is a big NO NO :-)

Comment: I dont want HOME -> POLO TOPS. I DONT want HOME there at all. or ALL CATEGORIES

Comment: @AmitBera:  we can avoid two rewrites like in my method. Please go through it friend

Answer (score 0):

Im sure all these awnsers will work but i found a much easier method.

First create a variable which take in the breadcrumb

```
<?php $test = $crumbs?>
```

Then `var_dump` it to check what your Name is being called mine was "title"

Create a variable which takes in the crumbs title

```
<?php $name = $_crumb ['title'];?>
```

Then create IF statements that check that the title is not the titles you do not want.

```
<li <?php if ($name != 'Home' ){?>
<?php if ($name != 'All Categories' ){?>
```

Comment: Though it solves your problem, this solution is not at all a global solution for the problem that is described in your own question. and is not the right way to do it. If you need to do it in clean way, you need to follow the "module" way. :-) Anyway, please accept any of the answer (including yours) that helped you to resolve the issue. Please dont leave your question as it is :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer [ravi patels](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41652/46249) solution, because this i what Magento just missed and should be in core. If you can add elements via layout update, you should also be able to remove them.

Btw ... i think there is something wrong with `!isset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName])) || ...`. Without `readonly` check ...

```
public function removeCrumb($crumbName)
{
    if (isset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName])) {
        unset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName]);
    }
}
```

---

#### Optional [#1](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/336/commits/d22855c4130940067d6657202546bb9c6afcfa55)

If you alread rewrite `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs` block, you can **fix** `addCrumb($crumbName, $crumbInfo, $after = false)` method, where 3rd parameter `$after` is not used. Just replace ...

```
$this->_crumbs[$crumbName] = $crumbInfo;
```

with

```
if ($after && isset($this->_crumbs[$after])) {
    $offset = array_search($after, array_keys($this->_crumbs)) + 1;
    $this->_crumbs = array_slice($this->_crumbs, 0, $offset, true) + array($crumbName => $crumbInfo) + array_slice($this->_crumbs, $offset, null, true);
} else {
    $this->_crumbs[$crumbName] = $crumbInfo;
}
```

#### Optional [#2](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/336/commits/d5d479b5da993e6546e1c0cd3a544aee9c38cb9d)

If you want to a crumbs **before** another, add this ...

```
public function addCrumbBefore($crumbName, $crumbInfo, $before = false)
{
    if ($before && isset($this->_crumbs[$before])) {
        $keys = array_keys($this->_crumbs);
        $offset = array_search($before, $keys);
        # add before first
        if (!$offset) {
            $this->_prepareArray($crumbInfo, array('label', 'title', 'link', 'first', 'last', 'readonly'));
            $this->_crumbs = array($crumbName => $crumbInfo) + $this->_crumbs;
        } else {
            $this->addCrumb($crumbName, $crumbInfo, $keys[$offset-1]);
        }
    } else {
        $this->addCrumb($crumbName, $crumbInfo);
    }
}
```